# phpmailer was working as of 12/4 prior to 2pm est

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer

ok so im at 30 hours non stop trying to figure out this code as to why it stopped working out of nowhere and its really starting to piss me off now.

it is a production server and was working just fine until title time.

here is my testemail.php that did work prior to this date-time.

```
<?php
require 'include\smtp\class.phpmailer.php';
require 'include\smtp\class.smtp.php';
set_time_limit(3600);
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object

$mail->Timeout = 3600;
$mail->IsHTML();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = "email";
$mail->Password = "pass";        
$mail->SetFrom( "email",  "Do Not Reply");
$mail->Subject = "test";
//$mail->AddAttachment($dir.str_replace("/", "\\", $row2["eventpdf"]));
$mail->Body = "testing";
$mail->AddAddress("email");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    } else {
    $error = 'Message sent!';

    }
    ?>
```

UPDATE:

i updated my class.phpmailer.php and class.smtp.php to vs 5.2.26 from github and applied the work around of

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => true,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
)
);
```

right before the if(!$mail line. this is a temp solution while i figure out why the ssl cert is pulling it from the wrong location and where to set the proper one. its pulling stuff from /usr/local/ssl however this is a windows machine and thinks its a linux one. also not using any prepackaged amp system. im using all separate installs. apache/php/mysql all alone.

fyi:

the verify_peer once set to true is what causes the issue. you can change anything else to true/false and it will send. once you change verify_peer to true it stops.

Comment: maybe you have a problem with the mail server not the php

Comment: gmail is my mailserver and i can login no problem with browser and phone and apps. i also have less secure enabled.

Comment: Random guess: they have fully switched to TLS1.2, and aren't supporting earlier protocols any more

Comment: and $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';   should be $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

Comment: tls doesnt work either but gives more detailed error. ssl doesnt give anything no matter what i change it to. 1-4.

Comment: You seem to actively avoiding taking even the most basic advice on how to load PHPMailer from the readme and every provided example. Do what it says and you might have more success. Also note that there seems to have been a problem with validating gmail certs recently, due to having old CA certificates - but that's covered in the troubleshooting guide and other questions on here.

Comment: Edit your question down to something readable, and make up your mind which version you're using; this is a mess.

Comment: i made a new cert many times and even got one from comodo. using self signed or comodo didnt resolve it. this phpmailer is the older version and worked fine. i have read all of your comments on github and i tried numerous times to update my code with the new phpmailer 6.0 and its causing more issues than just the ca like ive stated above. it cant find the location of the PHPMailer.php even with the given location i cant update it and idfk why! this is very frustrating!

Comment: Can you ping smtp.gmail.com if you connect to your server via SSH?

Comment: im displaying everything i have tried so i dont have to repeat myself over and over again with people saying try this that and whatever else someone thinks of so its all avoided. i want to remain using the older version because if i try to update to 6 its makes more problems.

Comment: i can ping it normal in cmd.exe if i use putty and try to ssh on 22 no i cannot. i have also made a firewall rule to have it open to smtp.gmail.com over 22/465/587

Comment: readme for 5.2 says to use require 'include\smtp\PHPMailerAutoload.php'; did so and does nothing. same error as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed correctly. Under PHPMailer troubleshooting download a new cacert.pem and inside your php.ini you need to scroll to the bottom(at least mine was at bottom) or search for cafile or capath and add the path and file. File needs to be the complete path to it because it gave me an error of it wasn’t. Like c:\certs\cacert.pem then restart your Apache server and either change verify_peer to true or remove all smtpoptions and it sends emails again with a certificate. Unsure if it works with any other certs but did with the one I downloaded from the site listed on troubleshooting PHPMailer page on GitHub.